# sql query between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

**form.php**

```
<form  action="dropdown.php" method="POST">
<?php
$month = array();
    for ( $i=1; $i<13; $i++ ) {
    $month = date('m', mktime(0,0,0,$i,2,2000));
    $sel = ( $i == date('n') ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
    $options1[] = "<option  value=\"{$month}\" {$sel}>{$month}</option>";
}
    $options_list1 = join("", $options1);
    echo "<select name=\"month\" >{$options_list1}</select>";
    for ( $j=1; $j<32; $j++ ) {
    $theday = date('d', mktime(0,0,0,0,$j,2000));
    $sel = ( $j == date('d') ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
    $options2[] = "<option  value=\"{$theday}\" {$sel}>{$theday}</option>";
}
    $options_list2 = join("\r\n", $options2);
    echo "<select name=\"day\" >{$options_list2}</select>";
    $arrivalyear = array(2013 => "2013",2014 => "2014");
    $selected = date("Y");
    echo '<select name="year">';
    foreach ($arrivalyear as $i => $v) {
    echo "<option  value=\"" . $i . "\"";
if ($i == $selected) echo " selected=\"selected\"";
    echo ">" . $v . "</option>";
    } 
    echo '</select>';
?>
<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;BETWEEN&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<?php
$month = array();
    for ( $i=1; $i<13; $i++ ) {
    $month = date('m', mktime(0,0,0,$i,2,2000));
    $sel = ( $i == date('n') ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
    $options1[] = "<option  value=\"{$month}\" {$sel}>{$month}</option>";
}
    $options_list1 = join("", $options1);
    echo "<select name=\"month1\" >{$options_list1}</select>";
    for ( $j=1; $j<32; $j++ ) {
    $theday = date('d', mktime(0,0,0,0,$j,2000));
    $sel = ( $j == date('d') ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
    $options2[] = "<option  value=\"{$theday}\" {$sel}>{$theday}</option>";
}
    $options_list2 = join("\r\n", $options2);
    echo "<select name=\"day1\" >{$options_list2}</select>";
    $arrivalyear = array(2013 => "2013",2014 => "2014");
    $selected = date("Y");
    echo '<select name="year1">';
    foreach ($arrivalyear as $i => $v) {
    echo "<option  value=\"" . $i . "\"";
if ($i == $selected) echo " selected=\"selected\"";
    echo ">" . $v . "</option>";
    } 
    echo '</select>';
?>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Date Filter">

</form>
```

There are two select option for dates  , if the user select `2014-02-10` and `2014-02-08` . It will show the dates between these two dates

I know this query but this is not working like the way i want because If the user select the 1st date and then 2nd date then my query will not perfom like i want

```
select * from mdx
  where mdx_timestamp >= '2014-02-10' and mdx_timestamp <= '2014-02-08'
```

if any have any solution to find the dates between two dates and the date is coming from db

Answer (score 1):

use `Between` Clause

`select * from mdx where mdx_timestamp between '2014-02-08' and '2014-02-10'`

Answer (score 0):

May be Your query should be like

```
select * from mdx where mdx_timestamp <= '2014-02-10' and mdx_timestamp >= '2014-02-08'
```

No date that exists greater than `2014-02-10` and less than `2014-02-08` logically.You need to do it in reverse

Answer (score 0):

Use `between` clause:

```
select * from mdx where mdx_timestamp between '2014-02-08' and '2014-02-10'
```

Alternatively:

```
select * from mdx 
  where mdx_timestamp between 
              least( '2014-02-08', '2014-02-10' )
              and
              greatest( '2014-02-08', '2014-02-10' )
```

***Refer to***:
[MySQL: expr BETWEEN min AND max](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have to add the time to the date otherwise it will not work like so:

```
select * from mdx where mdx_timestamp >= '2014-02-10 00:00:00' and mdx_timestamp <= '2014-02-08  23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT * FROM mdx WHERE mdx_timestamp >= "2014-02-08" AND mdx_timestamp <="2014-02-10";